# Invoking javascript file with dom access

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, visual-studio-2015, jint

I have a javascript file that has code with DOM access

```
var a=document.getElementById("abc").value
```

I have html file, that contains all DOM information

```
<html>...<input id="abc" ...></html>
```

Is there anyway to get C# invoke the javascript file, and return the value of `a`, back to the c# program?

In reality the JavaScript can be much more complex, and I need to channel those "interested values" back to C#, but let's just consider the simple example mentioning here.

Possible directions I could think is using https://jint.codeplex.com/, or Web browser control. The challenge here is that it not only involves the JavaScript, it also involving the HTML file.

What I want to know is:

1. Is there a way to channel variable value from JavaScript back to C#?
2. How to get JavaScript evaluate DOM elements from a HTML file?

Comment: why you are not trying  MVC 4 ?

Answer (score 1):

Using WebBrowser and Jint:

```
using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
            {
                browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                browser.DocumentText = @"<html><head/><body><input id=""abc"" value=""this is the value in input""></body></html>";
                // Wait for control to load page
                while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                    Application.DoEvents();
                dynamic d = (dynamic)browser.Document.DomDocument;//get de activex dom
                var jengine = new Jint.Engine();
                jengine.SetValue("document", d);
                try
                {
                    string val=jengine.Execute(@"var a=document.getElementById('abc').value;").GetValue("a").ToString(); 
                    Console.WriteLine(val);
                }
            catch (Jint.Runtime.JavaScriptException je)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(je);
            }
        }
```